# how find the middle point between 2 dates in Sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite, date

I have these dates:

`"2019-01-01" and "2019-01-05"`
,I need this `"2019-01-03"`

How can I perform this on Sqlite?
I tried `DateAdd(ms, DateDiff(ms, date1, date2), date1)/2` but this does not work in SQLite, this query given this error: `Result: no such column: ms`

Comment: Have a look at Sqlite documentation [Date functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Answer (score 2):

`sqlite` is not `mysql` or not `postgresql`

[This link](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) will display all functions that manipulate date.

For your question a solution can be :

```
 select datetime(strftime('%s','2019-01-01') + 
                   (strftime('%s','2019-01-05')-strftime('%s','2019-01-01'))/2, 
                'unixepoch');
```

Comment: Contrary to my previous comment, it is not a rounding issue in this particular case, but that should still be considered in the general case if "pure" dates are desires (i.e. without time components) since an even number of days will have the middle point fall at 12:00pm.  Instead **you need to remove the `'localtime'` argument.**  The difference between simple dates will be the same in any timezone, so doing a calculation with literal string dates can be interpreted as "local time" even though internally it considers it as UTC times.

Comment: If for some reason you need to consider time in the calculation, it can be worth converting to UTC then back to accurately consider changes in daylight saving, for example.  The you would need `datetime(strftime('%s','2019-01-01', 'localtime') + (strftime('%s','2019-01-05', 'localtime')-strftime('%s','2019-01-01', 'localtime'))/2, 'unixepoch', 'UTC') `